# Series sum approximation

Tags: series-expansion, approximation

Since there is no closed formula, as far as I know, to find the sum of

$$
\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{\log (n)}}
$$

I used `//N` to find an approximation and *Mathematica* gave me `0.69024445098278` in 0.04 seconds. The problem is that the given series converges SO slowly that an error less than 0.001 requires adding about $ 3\times 10^{434294} $ terms!

How does *Mathematica* manage to give fine approximations of series like this one?

Comment: Maybe this helps :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476492/value-of-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n-lnn2

Answer (score 24):

Writing:

```
NSum[(-1)^n/Sqrt[Log[n]], {n, 2, Infinity}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns"]
```

I get:

> 0.690243

which is what you want.

In particular, directly from [Numerical Evaluation of Sums and Products](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalEvaluationOfSumsAndProducts.html) you read:

> The way [NSum](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSum.html) works is to include a certain number of terms explicitly,
>   and then to try and estimate the contribution of the remaining ones.
>   There are three approaches to estimating this contribution. The first
>   uses the [Euler–Maclaurin Method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MaclaurinIntegrationFormulas.html), and is based on approximating the sum
>   by an integral. The second method, known as the [Wynn's Epsilon Method](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WynnsEpsilonMethod.html),
>   samples a number of additional terms in the sum, and then tries to fit
>   them to a polynomial multiplied by a decaying exponential. The third
>   approach, useful for alternating series, uses an alternating signs
>   method (cf. [Euler's Series Transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersSeriesTransformation.html)); it also samples a number of additional terms and approximates
>   their sum by the ratio of two polynomials ([Padé Approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PadeApproximant.html); cf. [Convergence Acceleration of Alternating Series](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/exp-math-9/fulltext.pdf)).

The links I've added them are not present in the official guide.

---

In light of all this, given a convergent alternating series with sum $\begin{aligned} S = \sum_{n = n_{min}}^{\infty} (-1)^n\,a_n \end{aligned}$, I can define the *Euler's transformation* (1755) as $\begin{aligned} S \approx \sum_{n = n_{min}}^{n_{max}} \frac{b_n}{2^{n + 1}} \end{aligned}$ (Knopp, 1990) committing a maximum error $R_{max} = \left|\frac{b_{n_{max}}}{2^{n_{max}}}\right|$, where $\begin{aligned} b_n := \sum_{m = n_{min}}^n (-1)^m\,\binom{n}{m}\,a_m \end{aligned}$. Now, writing in MMA:

```
EulerTransformation[nmin_, nmax_] := 
  Module[{b, m, n}, 
          b[n_] = Sum[(-1)^m Binomial[n, m] a[m], {m, nmin, n}];
          {Chop[NSum[b[n]/2^(n + 1), {n, nmin, nmax}]], 
           ScientificForm[N[Abs[b[nmax]/2^nmax]]]}
        ];

a[n_] := 1/Sqrt[Log[n]];

EulerTransformation[2, 24]
```

I get the sum and the maximum error committed:

> {0.690243, 2.68419*10^-6}

for $n_{max} = 24 \ll 3 \cdot 10^{434294}$.

---

Can you do better? The answer is yes and lies in the method of Henri Cohen, Fernando Rodriguez Villegas and Don Zagier (2000), above linked, on *Convergence Acceleration of Alternating Series*.

In particular, writing in MMA:

```
CohenVillegasZagierMethod[nmin_, nmax_] :=
   Module[{b, c, d, n, s},
           d = ((3 + Sqrt[8])^nmax + (3 - Sqrt[8])^nmax)/2;
           b = -1;
           c = -d;
           s = 0;
           Table[c = b - c;
                 s = s + c a[n + nmin] (-1)^nmin;                                
                 b = (n + nmax) (n - nmax) b/((n + 1/2) (n + 1)),
                {n, 0, nmax - 1}];
           {Chop[N[s/d]], ScientificForm[N[Abs[s/d^2]]]}
         ];

a[n_] := 1/Sqrt[Log[n]];

CohenVillegasZagierMethod[2, 8]
```

I get the sum and the maximum error committed:

> {0.690244, 1.03663*10^-6}

for $n_{max} = 8 < 24 \ll 3 \cdot 10^{434294}$.

Comment: Great! I got 14 correct decimals of Pi with 50 iterations using (-1)^(n+1)/(2n-1)

Answer (score 8):

Using identity:
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{2 n^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }} \, dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log (n)}}$$

then I have:

$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{\log (n)}}=\\\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } (-1)^n \int_0^{\infty } \frac{2 n^{-t^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }} \, dt=\\\int_0^{\infty } \left(\sum
   _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n \left(2 n^{-t^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right) \, dt=\\\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{2^{1-t^2} \left(-2^{t^2}-2 \zeta \left(t^2\right)+2^{t^2} \zeta
   \left(t^2\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }} \, dt$$

```
SUM = Sum[(-1)^n*(2 n^-t^2)/Sqrt[π], {n, 2, Infinity}] // Expand

(*2/Sqrt[π] - (2 Zeta[t^2])/Sqrt[π] + (2^(2 - t^2) Zeta[t^2])/Sqrt[π] *)

NIntegrate[SUM, {t, 0, 1, Infinity}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", WorkingPrecision -> 100]

(* 0.6902444509827817592722818703896943268934565604750857324852809551957617912451978141496673702035964490 *)
```

Comment: This is a slick solution!